# Granularity in hibernate ORM

Tags: hibernate

I googled it about granularity problem in hibernate. But I didn't find any good answer. I was asked this in an interview. Can somebody please explain it with appropriate example?

Answer (score 3):

An `ORM (Object Relational Mapping)` such as hibernate attempts to map the object model (interconnected graph of objects) in the object oriented Java application to the relational model (tables with rows and columns) of the database so that the two models can easily talk to each other. `Granularity Problem` is one of the several problems an ORM has to deal with to bridge the gap between the two models.

Granularity is the extent to which a system is composed of smaller components. Classes in the object model come in a range of different levels of granularity, whereas, only two levels of granularity is visible in SQL databases (owing to lack or poor support of user defined data types): Tables and columns of built-in data types such as *VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, INT*.

Consider, a `User` class which contains an object of `Address` class

```
           public class User{
               private String Name;
               private Address address;  
            }

            public class Address{
                private String street;
                private String city;
                private String country;
                private String zipCode;
            }
```

On the database side, same level of granularity i.e. adding a new `ADDRESS` SQL data type to `USERS` table is not possible. Also, instead of keeping the address information in a separate table, better design could be to keep the address information in the `USERS` table, in individual columns as below:

```
        create table USERS (
               USERNAME varchar(15) not null primary key,
               ADDRESS_STREET varchar(255) not null,
               ADDRESS_CITY varchar(255) not null,
               ADDRESS_COUNTRY varchar(5) not null,
               ADDRESS_ZIPCODE varchar(5) not null
            );
```

Here Java class `User` is at a higher level of granularity as compared to the corresponding `USERS` table. The result of this mismatch is more number of classes in object model than tables in relational model.

Hibernate and other ORMs based on Java Persistence API (JPA) allow entities like `User` to embed inside them other entities like `Address` (using @embeddable), so that it can map to the single database table like `USERS`.

Comment: Please clarify, does "classes in the object model" means the "data types of properties in the object"?

Answer (score 0):

you could look at this link

http://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/#granularity

It says that 
RDBMSs represent data in a tabular format (a spreadsheet is a good visualization for those not familiar with RDBMSs), whereas object-oriented languages, such as Java, represent it as an interconnected graph of objects.

That means the object relational mapping don't work properly .

overall i we need more granular objects that means we need more different type of objects but when we design database we are having less number of tables .

other wise  : no of class > no of table